# Having issue while printing specific value from df

Tags: python, pandas, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, element


Stock_Symbol=input("Enter the symbol of the stock\n")
Stock_URL="https://ticker.finology.in/company/"+Stock_Symbol

response=requests.get(Stock_URL)

soup=BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
data_array = soup.find_all(id="mainContent_clsprice")
df=pd.DataFrame(data_array)
a=(df[1])
print(a)
```

In the above code, I want to extract only the price which is 456 for today, but the value I am getting is [\n, [456.95], [], \n], is there any way to get the specific value while web scrapping

Comment: what symbol do you enter? after you use ```input```? so that we can replicate exactly.

Comment: I used SBIN as the symbol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need pandas to get that data !
This is a working example :

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, element


Stock_Symbol=input("Enter the symbol of the stock\n")
Stock_URL="https://ticker.finology.in/company/"+Stock_Symbol

response=requests.get(Stock_URL)

soup=BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
data = soup.find("div", {"id":"mainContent_clsprice"}).find("span", {"class": "Number"}).getText()

print(data)
```

And as output

```sh
Enter the symbol of the stock
itc
218.00
```